# error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’

Tags: openssl, rsa

I have the following code:

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

...
RSA *pubkey = RSA_new();
BIGNUM *modulus = BN_new();
...
pubkey->n = BN_new();
BN_copy(pubkey->n, modulus);
```

complied like so:

```
gcc rsatest.c -o rsatest -lcrypto
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
rsatest.c: In function ‘main’:
rsatest.c:57:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘RSA {aka struct rsa_st}’
  pubkey->n = BN_new();
        ^~
```

What is the problem here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RSA_set0_key(pubkey, modulus, exponent, NULL);
```

instead of

```
pubkey->n = BN_new();
BN_copy(pubkey->n, modulus);
pubkey->e = BN_new();
BN_copy(pubkey->e, exponent);
```

fix the issue.